# How to duplicate all bookmarked lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I would like to go though all bookmarked lines and duplicate them.

This would be an automated way to pressing F2 then Ctrl+D.

I've tried macros and two \1 with find and replace with regular expressions.

---------------------Example before------------------------

```
hostname RTA 
interface Loopback0
 ip address 203.250.13.41 255.255.255.0
interface Ethernet0
 ip address 203.250.14.1 255.255.255.0
router ospf 10
 network 203.250.13.41 0.0.0.0 area 1
 network 203.250.0.0 0.0.255.255 area 0.0.0.0
```

there are 8 lines of code above. i bookmark lines 2 & 4.

------------------------Example after-----------------

```
hostname RTA 
interface Loopback0
interface Loopback0
 ip address 203.250.13.41 255.255.255.0
interface Ethernet0
interface Ethernet0
 ip address 203.250.14.1 255.255.255.0
router ospf 10
 network 203.250.13.41 0.0.0.0 area 1
 network 203.250.0.0 0.0.255.255 area 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: And both (macros and RegEx) works?!? ;) Can you be more specific?

Comment: Both do not work, for example, if line 10 and 20 are bookmarked. i would like a line added into line 21 which is a copy of line 20. and a line added to line 11 which is a copy of line 10.

Comment: Yep - it's a N++ bug... Remove bookmark as soon as possible in macro you are recording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My inelegant solution to this was to:-

-add "##BOOKmarked LiNe##" to each bookmarked line

-run the following in a vbs file

-remove all "##BOOKmarked LiNe##" entries.

```
outFile="C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_loop1-out.txt"
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFileout = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)

Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
strLine= objFile.ReadLine
objFileout.Write strLine & vbCrLf
if strLine.contains("##BOOKmarked LiNe##") Then objFileout.Write strLine & vbCrLf
Loop
objFile.Close
objFileout.Close
```